# How to remove ('u')unicode from list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, unicode

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
d = [{'email': u'123@gmail.com', 'name': u'xxx'}, {'email': u'abc@gmail.com', 'name': u'xxx1'}, {'email': u'xyz@gmail.com', 'name': u'xxx2'}]
```

I want that unicode character to be removed, so my output should look like

```
d = [{'email': '123@gmail.com', 'name': 'xxx'}, {'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'name': 'xxx1'}, {'email': 'xyz@gmail.com', 'name': 'xxx2'}]
```

can anyone please tell me?

Comment: Why do you want that?  Note that the `u` is not actually stored in your data.  That's just Python telling you that the items are unicode strings.

Comment: When am doing Json.dumps it is showing be TypeError.

Comment: The 'u' only appears when you use 'repr' to get something suitable for digestion by Python, which means you are using the wrong tool for JSON export. That said, upgrade to Python 3, where the default string is already Unicode and those 'u' tags aren't necessary any more.

Comment: If you're getting an error from json.dumps, it's not from the Unicode. You should show the actual code and the traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also encode you unicode characters in utf-8 like:

```
In [2]: d = [{'email': u'123@gmail.com', 'name': u'xxx'}, {'email': u'abc@gmail.com', 'name': u'xxx1'}, {'email': u'xyz@gmail.com', 'name': u'xxx2'}]

In [3]: new_d = [{k: v.encode("utf-8") for k, v in elem.items()} for elem in d]
In [4]: new_d
Out[4]: 
[{'email': '123@gmail.com', 'name': 'xxx'},
 {'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'name': 'xxx1'},
 {'email': 'xyz@gmail.com', 'name': 'xxx2'}]
```

Comment: I am using python 2.6 so I have to use dict constructor, thanx a lot your solution works fine in later versions.